# Show existence of vector of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory, differential-topology

$ U ⊂ R^m$ is open and we have $f : U → R^n$. Prove if $df_a(u)$ exists, then $df_a(bu)$ exists and is equal to $b*df_a(u)$ for any $b \in R$ that is not 0.

I assumed $df_a(u)$  is a directional vector in the direction of a, and I used chain-rule to derive the result but I am not sure if it applies to directional vectors.

This was actually a quiz question that I couldn't get and hope to understand before my midterm. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If $df_a(u)$ is what you say it is, the result as stated is not true.

Comment: I assumed $df_a(u)$ was the total differential at the point $a$.

Comment: i am probably wrong then, because I did not fully understand what the notation is

Comment: @jamesblack are you familiar with the Jacobian matrix?

Comment: do you mean differential at point a with value u?

Comment: yes but in terms of linear algebra not real analysis

Comment: $u \in U$ so it's in the open set around the point $a$. Think of it as an open patch where the derivative is well-defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103726/discussion-between-cyclotomicfield-and-james-black).

Comment: Ok, the total differential is an $n\times m$ matrix. By definition, it is interpreted as a linear operator, so $df_a(bu)=b\,df_a(u)$ by definition. And it is not true that the total differential exists for an arbitrary function; lots of functions exist that are not differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that $df_a(u)$ denotes the directional derivative of $f$ at a point $a$ in the direction of $u$ (*not* the direction of $a$!).  The result in question then indeed follows from the chain rule (for ordinary functions of a single variable; no need to worry about a chain rule for directional derivatives): $df_a(u)$ is by definition $g'(0)$ where $g$ is defined by $g(t)=f(a+tu)$, and $df_a(bu)$ is by definition $h'(0)$ where $h(t)=f(a+tbu)$.  But $h(t)=g(bt)$ so by the chain rule $h'(0)=bg'(0)$.

If you are not comfortable using the chain rule in this way, this fact is also easy to verify directly from the definition of the directional derivative as a limit: you wish to show $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+tbu)-f(a)}{t}=b\cdot\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+tu)-f(a)}{t}$$ assuming the limit on the right exists.  To do so, just substitute $t'=tb$ on the left side and observe that a limit as $t\to 0$ is equivalent to a limit as $t'\to 0$.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation! why does this have to do with U being open btw? why cant U be closed U is the domain btw

Comment: and what is the intuitive meaning of this result?